# enums / union types in typescript / svelte

Tags: typescript, enums, svelte, union-types

i have the following problem with typescript enum / union types
when i have the following data structure

```js
    type Options =  SingleOptions | DualDiffOptions
     
    enum Modes {
        Single = "Single",
        DualDiff = "DualDiff",
    }

    type SingleOptions = {
        on_temp: String;
        off_temp: String;
        sensor_channel: String;
    };


    type DualDiffOptions = {
        sensor_cold_side: String;
        sensor_hot_side: String;
        on_temp: String;
        off_temp_diff: String;
    };


    type Data = {
        mode: Mode.Single;
        options: Options;
    };

    let data: Data = {
        mode: Modes.Single,
        options: {
            on_temp: "22",
            off_temp: "23",
            sensor_channel: "ch1",
        },
    };
```

when i now use the data object, typescript cant really figure out if its SingleOptions or DualDiffOptions,
how would on deal with this kind of situations..?

```html
<div>
            {#if data.mode == Modes.Single}
                <div>
                    {data.options.on_temp}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {data.options.off_temp}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {data.options.sensor_channel}
                </div>
            {/if}
            {#if data.mode == Modes.DualDiff}
                 <div>
                    {data.options.on_temp}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {data.options.off_temp_diff}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {data.options.sensor_cold_side}
                </div>
                <div>
                    {data.options.sensor_hot_side}
                </div>
                
            {/if}
</div>
```

in rust one can just create a Options enum with the different Options structs. but this seems to not be possible in typescript.

im new to typescript, and wanted to learn it because i kind of like types now after leaning rust, but i can see that typescript enums are not very usefull. compared to rust..

how would one deal with this sort of thing in typescript..?

this does not work as enum only takes values and not types

```js
enum Options {
  Single = SingleOptions;
  DualDiff = DualDiffOptions;
}

type Data = {
   mode: Mode.Single;
   options: Options;
 };

let data: Data = {
  mode: Modes.Single,
  options: Options.Single {
    on_temp: "22",
    off_temp: "23",
    sensor_channel: "ch1",
  }
}
```

regards.

Comment: I don't know whether it's the problem, but to quote the TypeScript Handbook *(their emphasis)*: [❌ **Don't** ever use the types `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Symbol`, or `Object` These types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used appropriately in JavaScript code. ✅ Do use the types `number`, `string`, `boolean`, and `symbol`.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).

Comment: I'm not quite following (possibly because I don't use Svelte, or possibly because I'm rushing out the door), but it sounds like you probably want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to explicitely link the `Mode` to the type of options, to tell TypeScript that single mode has single options, and dual mode has dual options.

The easiest way to do so is to use a discriminated union

```
type Data = { mode: Modes.Single, options: SingleOptions }
  | { mode: Modes.DualDiff, options: DualDiffOptions }
```

with this code you are basically saying that type Data can be of two forms, one where mode equals single, in which case options should be of the form SingleOptions, and one where it is with dual diff